# How to keep variable preserve while running script through ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, environment-variables

I am trying to run while loop with read through ssh:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh root@10.10.10.10 "cat /var/log/syncer/rm_filesystem.log | while read path; do stat -c \"%Y %n\" "$path"  >> /tmp/fs_10.10.10.10.log done"
```

But the issue is my variable $path is resolving on my localhost where as I want to resolve it on remote host so that it can read file on remote host and take stat of all folder/files listed in "rm_filesystem.log"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it working in a good way as it should be:

## !/bin/bash

ssh root@10.10.10.10 "cat /var/log/syncer/rm_filesystem.log | while read path; do stat -c '%Y "%n"' "\"'$path'\"" >> /tmp/fs_10.10.10.10.log done"

After reading bash man page I got this trick ..

Thanks everyone for help

Answer (score 1):

or put the ssh command line into single quotes rather than double.  then the command will be passed as is without any substitution at the local end.
i.e.

```
ssh root@10.10.10.10 'cat /var/log/syncer/rm_filesystem.log | while read path; do stat -c "%Y %n" "$path"  >> /tmp/fs_10.10.10.10.log done'
```

Answer (score 0):

ssh user@host "bash -s" < yourscript.sh

What is currently happening is that the script is being parsed on your local machine and then sent in its entirety to the remote machine. So by the time it gets there, the $PATH variable will have already been replaced by your local $PATH value.

What the example above does is open a bash session on your remote machine and set bash to read from stdin (see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoking-Bash)

You then pass in the script (which you have typed into an external file) so that it executes directly on the remote machine.

This way, there is no local parsing of the script, and thus no replacement of the environment variable.